# About java compiling

Tags: java, compilation, cmd

I programmed two java classes (`Coordinate.java` and `Orienteering.java`) using Eclipse. These classes are stored in `C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Orienteering\Orienteering\src\jp\co\worksap\global`

The package is `jp.co.worksap.global.Orienteering`. I want to know how can I compile the two files in Windows command line and run it? `Orienteering.java` is the main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open the command line, then change to the source folder

```
cd C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Orienteering\Orienteering\src\jp\co\worksap\global 
javac -g Orienteering.java Coordinate.java
```

That should generate two corresponding `.class` files (with debug symbols). Then move up a few directories and execute `java` like,

```
cd C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Orienteering\Orienteering\src\
java -cp . jp.co.worksap.global.Orienteering
```

**note** alternatively, the `javac` line could have been `javac -O *.java` (which would not include debug symbols and would *optimize* the build, and would compile any other java source files). Also, it is more typical to use a tool like ant, maven, gradle or sbt for java builds.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse there is an option to compile it for you. I believe it's:
File -> Export -> Runnable Jar File -> [Select the classes] -> Select Location -> Run the JAR File that gets created in that location.

As far as I know, I think Windows CMD can only compile one Java Class.

Comment: Several classes can be compile in CMD. The [javac doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html): `javac [ sourcefiles ]` with sourcefiles as `One or more source files to be compiled`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Goto your source directory using cd command:

```
cd C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Orienteering\Orienteering\src
```

Compile your classes using javac

```
javac jp\co\worksap\global\Coordinate.java jp\co\worksap\global\Orienteering.java
```

To run your program:

```
java -cp . jp.co.worksap.global.Orienteering
```